# Xcode Run Script unable to call nodejs during build

Tags: xcode

I am building an app using Cordova. And trying to minify and merge js and css files during build time. Therefore, I wrote a perl script to call nodejs to execute my javascript to do the minify and merge stuff.

The nodejs part is work when I execute the script in Terminal. Then I try to integrate the script to Xcode Run Script section and it will be called during build time. The script can be executed without problem. However, the javascript and css files do not perform minify and merge. It seems the nodejs script is not working. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Following is the perl script:

```
if($ARGV[0] eq "-clean") {
  print "Cleaning up...\n";
  system("rm -rf temp");
  system("rm -rf publish");
  exit(0);
}

my $arg_list = join(" ",@ARGV);
system( "node tools/publish.js publish.workflow.js $arg_list" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I decided to move the perl script to shell script. And enable to run node.js script by following command:
/usr/local/bin/node tools/publish.js publish.workflow.js -nomin -force